# Integrating youtube videos in django sites

Tags: python, django, youtube

How can I give a YouTube link and embed that video in a django template?

Comment: What have you tried? Youtube gives you embed snippets. Have you tried putting that into your templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just right on the youtube video and select Copy Embed HTML and Paste it in your template.

Example:

```
<object style="height: 390px; width: 640px"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/v1gTI4BOPUw?version=3"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/v1gTI4BOPUw?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390"></object>
```

Comment: There are other options in the embed form, that gives you other options. The one above, is the old style. The new style uses an iframe. But both will do the job.

Comment: The above one is working fine can u please advise how to use the same using an iframe

Comment: Here is the code I get from another video:
`<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UnBlst3T7bY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Answer (score 5):

Little self-promo, but you can try [django-embed-video](https://github.com/yetty/django-embed-video). It provides you simple embeding of Youtube and Vimeo videos, thumbnails etc.